# How to prevent audio recording in apps?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm developing an app for displaying videos. I want to prevent the app from screen recording and screenshots and achieved it by `window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)`. But I'm unable to prevent the audio recording of the video.

My code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        super.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar_1)
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video)

        videoView = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.videoView)

        videoView!!.setVideoPath(path)

        ctlr = MediaController(this)
        ctlr!!.setAnchorView(videoView)
        videoView!!.setMediaController(ctlr)

        videoView!!.start()

        detectAudioRecording(this)
}
```

I tried to detect if other apps are using microphone by using `UsageStateManager` and the code is as follows

```
public static void detectAudioRecording(final Context context) {

        AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        int mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS,
                android.os.Process.myUid(), context.getPackageName());

        if (mode != AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        /*if (otherAppAudioTimer != null) {
            otherAppAudioTimer.cancel();
        }*/

        Timer otherAppAudioTimer = new Timer();
        otherAppAudioTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                final List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_YEARLY, now - (1000 * 60 * 60), now);
                if (queryUsageStats != null && queryUsageStats.size() > 0) {
                    SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<>();
                    for (UsageStats usageStats : queryUsageStats) {
                        mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
                    }
                    if (!mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                        String currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                        boolean hasRecordAudio = context.getPackageManager()
                                .checkPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, currentApp)
                                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                        if (context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName().equals(currentApp)) {
                            Log.e("hasAudio", "Current app is self");
                            return;
                        }


                        if (hasRecordAudio) {
                            //the current app can record audio
                        } else {
                            //the current app cannot record audio
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }, 0, 3000);
    }
```

But still, the issue prevails.

Is there a way to prevent it??

Comment: Please post some code, so that we can help you.

Comment: I've added my code above, kindly check it out.

Comment: Hi @user1850484 are u found a solution

Comment: u can not stop audio recording 
but u can detect that and then u should stop your app and ask user to stop recording app to able to continue use your app